# Defining a Report to run against a Restful service

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

I am trying to design a system that can allow users to define reports, and store the definitions in a database.The definitions can specify which fields to include and the sort order - no aggregate functions.

The reports can be run from the web site, or via a scheduled task runner which emails the user the data in PDF, RTF or CSV format.

The data source is a WCF service - not SQL.

I have looked at SSRS where you can define reports in RDL, but I'm not sure how you go about plugging this into an object data source.

Most of the reporting tools I've looked into involve using their designer and display plugins which is not possible here.

Has anyone come across anything that will at least give me the data from the report - not necessary to parcel it up as PDF/RTF/CSV etc as that can be a separate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS does not do RDL. You're thinking of SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services). You may want to look into building a model and letting your users use [Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). One thing to note is that querying web services from an XML Data Source in Reporting Services requires a good understanding of how to read WSDL files.

The following references are very useful for building XML queries in Reporting Services:

1. [Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa964129%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
2. [XML Query Syntax for Specifying XML Report Data (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345251%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)
3. [Element Path Syntax for Specifying XML Report Data (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365158.aspx)

Also see [Home » Article Discussions » Article Discussions by Author » Discuss content posted by Michael Davis » Report Server Diagnostic Reports](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic859325-2580-9.aspx) page 9 on SqlServerCetnral.com. I've written a post about halfway down the page that gives a very detailed example of querying some Reporting Services web services for information about reports.

Comment: Oops - yes indeed I meant SSRS.

Comment: Using Report Builder is not an option unfortunately - we're not building very complex reports, mostly just defining fields and sort orders, but it has to be done through a web-page interface in keeping with the rest of the app. Thanks for the links - I'll look through them over the next few days.

Comment: If that's the case, you may want to look at a product called ActiveReports from Data Dynamics. You could also design a regular SSRS report and call it from the application by using the Report Server Web Service. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787(v=sql.105).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render(v=sql.105).aspx.